# Rails and JQuery-Load DB data into Textfields for save and delete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have below data in database.My requirement-I have two options in dropdwon Get and Set. If i select Set option from dropdown , textfields along with checkbox needs to be created inside table dynamically with values of database ParaName,Datatype,Values as below.User can edit and delete records by selecting checkbox.I am new to ruby on rails.Can someone help,how to implement this?

UI Design look like below format

```
 ParaName DataType  Value

Textfield1 Textfield2 Textfield3  
TestData1   String     test      Checkbox
TestData2   boolean    true      Checkbox
TestData3   int        3         Checkbox

Button   Button
Save     Delete
```

DATABASE

```
ParaName|DataType|Value
TestData1|String  |test
TestData2|boolean |true 
TestData3|int     |3
```

Thanks,
Suba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The get/set dropdown can use the data-remote attribute to fire javascript through the controller, like this in `[name of controller method].html.erb`

```
<%= select_tag :type, options_for_select([ "Get", "Set" ]), include_blank: true, data: { remote: true, url: '/same_path' } %>
<div id="fields"></div>
```

In the controller

```
respond_to :html, :js
```

[name of controller method].js.erb file

```
$('#fields').html("<%= j render partial: 'fields' %>");
```

In `_fields.html.erb` render the fields as necessary. You can get the type that was selected in the get/set dropdown with `params[:type]`. If you need to load database objects in the controller to work with in any of the partials, you can do so like this

```
respond_to do |format|
  @types = Model.all
  format.html {
    # perform logic here for the html view
  }
  format.js {
    # perform logic here for the javascript view
  }
end
```